# Does the StuckThreadMaxTime parameter in Weblogic 10.3 abort the thread?

Tags: multithreading, timeout, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I get below message on application console when a some process takes unusually long time to complete. Does this message imply that my thread is aborted, or can it continue after this ?

> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for q
>   ueue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "609" seconds working on the request
>    "Http Request: /getSunPayment.do", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "
>   600" seconds

App Details: J2EE Struts app running on Weblogic 10.3, JRockit 6 JDK with 512MB heap.

Any help in clearing the doubt will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuck thread status is informational, WebLogic will not block, interrupt or kill the stuck threads, they will run to completion (if they can). Now, I must say that having HTTP requests taking more than 10mn is not really an appropriate use of HTTP.